# Powershell script to track user directory access

Tags: windows, powershell

I know about the FileWatcher in Windows but is there a way to track even if a user only enters a directory? I just found code for opening, editing and deleting files.

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\inetpub"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value $logline
          }    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action

while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: What does "enter a directory" mean? And I assume you're aware of file security auditing?

Comment: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/how-to-track-and-monitor-who-and-when-someone-accesses-a-folder-on-your-computer/

Comment: `$watcher.NotifyFilter` defaults to `FileName, DirectoryName, LastWrite` for me. Check `[System.IO.NotifyFilters].GetEnumValues()`, try at least `$watcher.NotifyFilter = $watcher.NotifyFilter -bOR [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastAccess`. Check `$watcher | Get-Member -MemberType Event`, try registering all event types.